# Report Service Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need help in a error on Reporting service.
I don't always get this error, just sometimes, but I need to solve it.

[image: Error!]

The description is this: For more information about this error, navigate to the report server on the local server machine or enable remote errors.

I already checked the .log file and I found this:

```html
Error in getting session data: Invalid or Expired Session: fnxgxhjuveugvd552qfyv3fw
session!ReportServer_0-6!4b0!03/18/2015-10:51:29:: i INFO: LoadSnapshot: Item with session: fnxgxhjuveugvd552qfyv3fw, reportPath: , userName: doman/user not found in the database
```

Do you know anything about it?

Thank you all.

Comment: Looks like you dont have proper permissions for that user.

Answer (score 0):

from the log you can see this message at the end "doman/user not found in the database" which is basically telling you that the user trying to run the report does not exist or more likely doesn't have all the required permissions.

Check that you (or the report server user) have access to all the tables that the report is pulling data from.

Answer (score 0):

May Can solve it by Try Catch on Reporting Code

### see this example

```
Public Shared Dim sPara1 As String= ""
Public Shared Dim sPara2 As String= ""


Public Function getPara1() As String



 TRY
        sPara1=Report.Parameters!Machine_NO.Value(0)
  CATCH
        sPara1 = "Not Select"
  END TRY

     Return sPara1
End Function


Public Function getPara2() As String

  TRY
        sPara2=Report.Parameters!Machine_NO.Value(1)
  CATCH
        sPara2 = "Not Select"
  END TRY

         Return sPara2
End Function
```

---

```
get Data by Expression
=Code.getPara2()
```